# Having an issue using JSoup for web scraping

Tags: java, web-scraping, jsoup

I am having an issue where I can't read the source code using JSoup. I'm in a company that runs a proxy.

I'm sending an auth with the proxy and seems to be working fine, but I'm not getting any code back. All I got back is a message with:

> Raw HTTP Request received by this server: GET
>   http://www.google.com/search?q=test HTTP/1.1 Accept-Encoding: gzip
>   User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:25.0)
>   Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0 Referer: http://www.google.com Host:
>   www.google.com Accept: text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*;
>   q=.2 Proxy-Connection: keep-alive

No matter what URL I try to access I always get a similar message and I can't seem to get the full code back to work with.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", proxyHost);
    System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", proxyPort);
    System.setProperty("http.proxyUser", authUser);
    System.setProperty("http.proxyPassword", authPassword);

    String url = "http://www.google.com/search?q=test";
    Document document = null;
    try {
        document = Jsoup.connect(url)
                .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0")
                .referrer("http://www.google.com")
                .timeout(1000*5)
                .get();
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (HttpStatusException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println(document);

    for (Element result : document.select("h3.r a")){
        final String title = result.text();
        final String hyper = result.attr("href");
        System.out.println(title + " -> " + hyper);
    }
}
```

*edit
I have tried other websites, all just retrieve a similar message.

Comment: Use some other url than google.you have to read robot.txt file for allowed pages for scrapping.

Comment: I have used other websites, all give the same reply message

Comment: Do you have an error (exception) ? If not, replace `System.out.println(document);` with `System.out.println(document.html());` to see the whole result page content. What do you see ?

Comment: ...and double check the return status code with `System.out.println(response.statusCode());`

Comment: There are no exception errors. The `System.out.println(document.html());` prints the same message shown in my question but wrapped into an html body with 5 lines only. I haven't found how to get the `response.StatusCode()` to work, the complete code I have is what it is shown in my question. Where do I get the `response` from?

Comment: Instead of `Jsoup.....get();` do `Jsoup....method(Connection.Method.GET).execute()`. Then you have the response and can do e.g. `response.statusCode()` for the status code or `response.parse()` to get the Document as before.

Comment: @Simon what the source code you want to read it? all sources codes of web site that google engine displays it?

Comment: I tried your code and it prints MyBroadband Speed Test -> http://speedtest.mybroadband.co.za/
Speedtest by Ookla - The Global Broadband Speed Test -> http://www.speedtest.net/
Fibre Speed Test - MWeb -> http://www.mweb.co.za/help/Fibre/FaultsandTroubleshooting/FibreSpeedTest.aspx
AT&T High Speed Internet Speed Test -> http://speedtest.att.com/speedtest/
 .....etc